# SQL error in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The following code

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #temp

SELECT *
INTO #temp
FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl)
```

Gives me a syntax error right after last parenthesis

I don't understand why at all

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need subquery:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #temp
FROM tbl;
```

Or add alias:

```
SELECT t.*
INTO #temp
FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl) AS t
```

You can also use CTE for more complex subqueries:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *
   FROM tbl
)
SELECT cte.*
INTO #temp
FROM cte;
```

Comment: Wel that isn't the whole code actually the select * from tbl is actually a sub query

Comment: @Kamster You need to add alias

Answer (score 2):

The `SELECT * FROM tbl` should have an alias defined.

```
SELECT t.*
INTO #temp
FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl) t
```